# Load a Panda Dataframe with timestamp columns having blank values into Teradata

Tags: python, pandas, teradata

I have a dataframe with timestamp columns (datetime64). I have a dummy value 1900-01-01 00:00:00 that I need to convert to blank spaces. When I do this and push the df to teradata it throws an Invalid Timestamp error :

```
#Replacing 4 timestamp columns having dummy value with blank spaces
df[ts_cols[dt]]=df[ts_cols[dt]].astype(str).str.strip().replace('1900-01-01 00:00:00','')
# Converting other null columns to blanks
df=df.astype(object).where(pd.notnull(df),'')

print(type(df2['timestamp_col1']))

It gives me <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

How do i successfully convert the dummy value to blank and push the dataframe to an existing table in teradata having timestamp(0) datatype?

Comment: You cannot cast an empty string as a timestamp.  Teradata will accept a null, assuming your column is defined as nullable.

Comment: @Andrew I am not sure i quite understand. The issue is if i upload the df with a dummy date like 1900-01-01 00:00:00, teradata recognizes the string and converts it into a timestamp. However if i convert this date into a blank value, it doesnt ignore it. I am using the Teradata module within python. 
Not sure if there is a paramenter to ignore nulls when a dataframe to teradata

Comment: If I'm reading your post correctly, in pandas you are replacing the value '1900-01-01 00:00:00' with '' (an empty string).  You are then attempting to insert that value into a timestamp column.  You cannot insert an empty string into a timestamp column.

Comment: @Andrew That's correct and I understand that. Is there a work around to avoid this? I dont want my table to have this dummy date value.

Comment: If your target column is nullable, you can insert a null value.  I can't tell you how to do that in Pandas though.  Maybe replace the dummy value with NaN?  If your target column is not nullable, you have to insert a legit timestamp.

Comment: I tried converting the dummy value to nan and export it to teradata but it is giving me an Invalid timestamp error again. Is there an alternative in the teradata module for python?

Comment: Googling around a bit, try `none` instead of `NaN`.

Comment: Sorry for getting back late on this. Thank You @Andrew , your solution works. i will post what I did to load the timestamps having nulls into teradata.

Answer (score 1):

So below is what I do to handle the missing dates:

I convert the dummy date to NaT values.

```
#Replacing 4 timestamp columns having dummy value with blank spaces
df[ts_cols[dt]]=df[ts_cols[dt]].astype(str).str.strip().replace('1900-01-01 00:00:00',pd.NaT)
#Put in None for Teradata to read null values
        df=df.where((pd.notnull(df)),None)
```

The dataframe with timestamp values is in object datatype but when loading into teradata, you can assign timestamp(0) or timestamp(6) in your fastload script and create a table before loading the data through the teradata module.

Comment: You say you convert them to NaT, implying that's the key to making things work with Teradata.  However, the code just below that converts them to None and the comment seems to imply that's the key for Teradata.  Can you clarify?  From what I'm seeing elsewhere, including for NaN as well, it seems you have to use None for loading to Teradata.